# react js c'ant fetch from database - node js api server keeps loading

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, rest

Hi guys i'am new in react js and node.js. So , I have a problem with fetching users list from database with node rest api
so at first this screen appears without displaying users list
then i had this error that i can't gues where the problem is !
help please
ps* excuse me for the captures i had problem with code publication

[image]
[image]
[image]

here is my userlist.js and app.js code

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post code as code, not images. Also try to make a minimal but relevant example that can reproduce the problem (and not your entire code).

Answer (score 0):

you are importing some components from `react` package at your `UserList`:

```
import { Button, ButtonGroup, Table } from 'react';
```

These components are going to be undefined since React doesn't have built-in components. These components import should come from another library or from the specific file if you've created them.

since you are using bootstrap you should import as:

```
import { Button, ButtonGroup, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: well, i'm sorry but i did't guess what should i do !

Comment: do you mean you don't know what you should do to fix it?

Comment: well, depends what library you are using for component styles. bootstrap?

Comment: ok edited my answer. you should import fom 'react-bootstrap'